# Getting the left part text of an EditText with Spans

Tags: java, android, split, android-edittext, spannablestring

My Android app has an EditText in its layout.

The EditText can contain text with optional ImageSpans.

At a certain point the user can perform some editing, that is, text can be edited and/or spans can be removed.

I get the caret position with

```
 int caretPosition= editText.getSelectionStart();
```

I need to know at this point, the text on the left, without the spans.

I mean, if no spans are present on the left the returned text is just what is expected, while if some spans are present, the text has no spaces or other characters in place of spans.

Example

```
aaaaaaaaaaa<span>bbbbbb<span>cccc_dddddd<span>eeeeee
```

the character _ is here for the cursor position (but it has not any space).

My goal is to get this string:

```
aaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbcccc
```

It is difficult because it seems that spans are like a single char, but I am not sure. And I do not know how to split an editable to iterate on the left part.

How to achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried using regular expressions after splitting the String from the start to the selection start?

Comment: @Nizar if you refer to the text, it has not the spans' HTML part in it

Comment: @Nizar When you get the text from an Editable you do not get also the spans' HTML so you have nothing to apply the regular expression to when searching for spans. Otherwise I am not understanding your suggestion. Try to write some code to an answer.

Comment: Can you share your code please ? I am trying to recreate a similar situation, and I'm not getting near your case

Comment: @Nizar please look at my answer

Comment: I did, however `editText.getText().substring` works for me even with Spannables. I do not have the issue you have, the issue you have isn't being caused by Spannables

Comment: @Nizar There is no issue. In my question I just make an example of what I want to achieve, and my answer provides the solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution:

```
int caretPosition=editText.getSelectionStart();
Spannable spannable=editText.getText();
String leftPartWithoutSpans=spannable.subString(0,caretPosition).toString();
```